# Can't sell the gold to the commodities market

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have gold in my cargo that I mined, found a station that imports it, but don't have an option to sell it in the commodities market.

Do I need to do something to the gold underneath the hopper, currently it says it is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to mine: 1 mining laser, 2 refinery, 3 cargo space.

Mine a chunk off, collect it, go into the right menu into cargo. Choose which ore to refine. Then build it up to 100 percent.

This gives you one cargo of whatever you mined.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you have a question (to help clarify his question), please place it in the comments.